# Golang Text representation as decimal string

Tags: go

How to convert "Hello" to string "72101108108111"

```
[]byte("Hello")=> [72 101 108 108 111]
```

Comment: What have you tried, what didn't work out. You should be able to write a for loop over a byte slice and fmt.Sprintf with %d.

Answer (score 2):

```golang
byteStr := []byte("Hello")
var result string
for _, i := range byteStr {
    result += fmt.Sprintf("%d", i)
}
fmt.Println(result)
```

Comment: I only meant to re-indent, but I also fixed your answer: you were missing the final print statement :)